# MongoDB - ON DUPLICATE KEY ..UPDATE behaviour

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I already checked many similar responses, and I feel nothing is answers this question clearly or the answers are not correct.

Question:

```
db.todos.insert({_id:1, name:'Test1'})
db.todos.insert({_id:2, name:'Test2'})
```

Above 2 documents added without issue. Now I am trying to use update with **upsert** which suppose to insert if found a duplicate key.

```
db.todos.update({name:'Test3'},{_id:2, name:'Test4'},{upsert:true})
```

But this gives the following error:

```
11000 duplicate key error index: todos.todos.$_id_  dup key: { : 2.0 }
```

My Question is, is there a way to implement ON DPULICATE KEY ..UPDATE behaviour on MongoDB ?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve in simple words, i.e. "if a document exists that matches criteria A and B, do this, else do that?" I think there's an answer to your question, but the update statement with the Test3 and Test4 values is completely irritating

Comment: OP, please edit question: 'Test3' -> 'Test2', because the error you encounter is after you execute the update statement *a second time*, which truly is not reflected in the question text :)

Comment: You havent understand my point here..
01. I want to implement ** ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ** behaviour
02. With Insert I think it is not possible (please correct me if I am wrong)
03. I put **'Test3'** deliberately because, if I put **'Test2'**, it will match the existing record and do the update. But what Mongo document says is, if it doesn't find matching record it will try to INSERT because I am sending the **'upsert:true'**

Comment: If you want to do this why don't you put the _id into the condition instead? It will still be written out in the event of an insert which will make a duplicate eky update

Answer (score 0):

Change `{_id:2, name:'Test4'}` to `{name:'Test4'}`

There is no need to assign your _id, MongoDB will generate a unique id for you. I understand there may be a few use cases where it is desirable to create a custom _id; however, I think that should be done sparingly.

Comment: I want to try, DUPLICATE KEY..so removing _id is not an option here

Comment: Ok, then that is not possible. You would need to handle that at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

`db.todos.update({name:'Test3'},{_id:2, name:'Test4'},{upsert:true})`

means find a doc with name `Test3` ,if no such doc,create a doc with _id:2,name:'Test4'.

since there is no such row, it would try to insert {_id:2,name:'Test4'} which conflicts with existing _id:2.